# Android game: remove padding either side of screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, padding

I am relatively new to Android and am in the process of making a pretty basic game. I want to know how to remove the padding at either side of the main game screen, so that the game will take up the whole screen of whatever device is being used.

I originally thought it had something to do with the dimens.xml file:

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I tried changing both of these to 0dp but the white padding remains on the screen.
Also - in activity_play_game.xml I have the following:

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

And I'm thinking this may have something to do with it? Does anybody know where I'm going wrong? 
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this as your Activit layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

</RelativeLayout>
```

You should see whole screen filled with black. Then try to add this inside

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Margin Padding Test" />
```

And try to add `android:padding="20dp"` and `android:layout_margin="20dp"` into both RelativeLayout and TextView. When you try different combination of those attributes you should be able to update your layout to look as you need.

Margin change how layout is positioned in its parent.

Padding change how layout is positioned within itself.

Comment: Great answer!  After playing around with different combinations I got it sorted! Thank you :D